# Can't seem to stop background music

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

In my viewcontroller.h file I have:

```
- (void)startBackgroundMusic;

- (void)stopBackgroundMusic;

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

In my viewcontroller.m I have:

```
- (void)startBackgroundMusic
{
    NSError *err;
    NSURL *file = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@" DK" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file error:&err];
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"error in audio play %@",[err userInfo]);
        return;
    }
    [_audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

    _audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [_audioPlayer setVolume:.5];
    [_audioPlayer play];
}

- (void) stopBackgroundMusic {  
    [_audioPlayer pause];
}
```

In my MyScene.m file when I click a switch I have off I run:

```
[vc stopBackgroundMusic];
```

and I also have:

```
ViewController *vc;
```

declared above with viewcontroller.h imported.

This doesn't work. It plays fine but I just can't stop it. It seems easy to accomplish but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Try stop instead of pause.  startBackgroundMusic should probably call stop before allocating a new AVAudioPlayer.  Maybe check if _audioPlayer is nil or not in startBackgroundMusic.  Maybe you have two playing at once?

Comment: Ok I switched pause to stop and I surrounded the code in startBackgroundMusic with a if(_audioPlayer == nil){ but still it doesn't work. I'm trying to call stop right when my scene loads and its not working so something is going on where it seems like its not communicating with the ViewController